# endpoint para traer todas las subscripciones mercadopado

Tags: mercadopago

Existe alguna forma de traer todas las subscripciones que tengo hechas a mis clientes?

Tenemos alredor de 300 subscripciones y para conciliar queremos ver que todas las que están en mercadopago sean igual que las que tenemos en nuestro sistema.

Acá veo que siempre tengo que pasarle un id, pero que pasa si el ID no lo tengo o lo perdí? Como puedo saber los ids de las subscripciones?

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/api-docs/custom-checkout/plans/subscriptions/

Comment: Hola, no hay nadie que pueda responder esto?

Comment: por lo pronto, las suscripciones y planes solo pueden ser consultados de forma individual, esto corresponde a la nueva version, si necesitas la búsqueda podrías operar con la version antigua /preapprovals que si disponen de un search https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/api-docs/basic-checkout/subscription-payments/